# WinUI 3 C++ - Choose appo theme

Tags: c++, xml, xaml, winui-3

I'm developing a WinUI 3 C++ app for Windows 11 and the app automatically defaults to the theme chosen by Windows. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: The user chooses the Windows theme, not Windows. Why would you want to change the settings that the user of the computer has selected as their preference?

Comment: You should add winui-3 and xaml tags to your question.

Comment: @Sergio thanks i will do that!

Comment: @KenWhite Because I want the user to choose theme,and some ui object in the drak mode is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to change the overall app theme to the windows default theme is:

```
if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement rootElement)
{
    rootElement.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Default; //Also: Dark or Light
}
```